# Image Rating using Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to give rating to some image using selenium.

I gave rating as `4`(clicked on 4th star) and i found the `xpath` of rating field using firebug add on. the xpath is

```
css=img[alt="4"]
```

So, i wrote

```
selenium.click("css=img[alt="4"]");
```

but it is giving error..

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't find an [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), but a [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

XPath solution:

```
selenium.click("xpath=//img[@alt='4']");
```

CSS selector solution:

```
selenium.click("css=img[alt=4]");
```

Comment: btw The linked docs are really helpful and they are a good read, too.

Comment: Yes. it is a css selector. i tried the above code. but it is not selecting the rating. Also no error.

Answer (score 0):

Giving which error??If it is element not found use xpath as

```
xpath=//img[@alt='4']
```

Comment: error is coming because am using semicolon inside another semicolon.

Comment: if i use selenium.click("css=img[@alt='4']"); it is giving error as element not found.

Comment: and if i use selenium.click("css=img[alt='4']"); no error is coming. but nothing is happening. i mean it is not selecting the rating..

Comment: If _nothing_ happened (no error and the command test went on), that means that it went ok. Are you sure that's the only rating image on the page? Maybe it clicked another one? If not, the click may have not worked - then something's just bad.

Comment: You can use [highlight()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_Selenium_ISelenium_Highlight.htm) to see what element got found.

Comment: there is only one image to rate. and nothing happened to it.

Comment: Try using selenium.ClickAt also use highlight so that you can able to judge where click is taking place

Comment: If there's no exception and literally nothing happens, then Selenium thinks it clicked successfully. Can we see the HTML of the element holding the image which should handle he click? Is it an async script, or is it an `<a>` element?